# what would be the best approach to extract one language form wiktionary?

Tags: xml, mediawiki, wiktionary

I have searched but not found what I want, which is:

the best and most efficient to extract all Italian words, etymologies and parts of speech... including plural forms of words (amico, amichi) from wiktionary. I would like to put it into either a CSV (maybe too larg though) or a MySQL db as pure text (not blobs).

I want essential a record for each Italian word in English.

mwdumper keeps crashing too.

any advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I created a small Java program which extracts part of speech (verb, nound, adjective, adn so on) from the en.wiktionary XML dump, [here](https://github.com/jacopofar/wikidump-tools), it uses TSV but can be adapted easily.

Comment: Jackopo,I tried to compile it and got this error:POSfromDump.java:20: error: class GeneraDatabasePOS is public, should be declared in a file named GeneraDatabasePOS.java
public class GeneraDatabasePOS {
(sorry i have never compiled java before)

Comment: You have to save it in a file called as the class, that is, GeneraDatabasePOS.java. You'll also have to change the lines of code containing the file paths.

Comment: Also you'll have to put it into a folder called "generazione" and run it with `java generazione.GeneraDatabasePOS`

Comment: You can see an updated version [here](https://github.com/jacopofar/wikidump-tools) or directly download the file "POS_list_IT_mar_2013.txt", it's 8.7 MB and contains 486481 terms.